50's movie about library employees who are scared a computer will replace their jobs
I think it was black and white, and it was about a group of female library employees. I think their job was to memorize obscure trivia to answer questions that people phone in, like a primitive Google. The library gets a big computer that can gather data from millions of books, and the employees are scared it'll make their jobs redundant, so they sabotage it and it breaks. At the end their boss explains that the computer was there to make their jobs easier, not replace them.
Ring any bells?

Sounds like historical fact, not fiction.

I believe the movie is Desk Set. http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050307/

The mysterious man hanging about at the research department of a big
  TV network proves to be engineer Richard Sumner, who's been ordered to
  keep his real purpose secret: computerizing the office. Department
  head Bunny Watson, who knows everything, needs no computer to unmask
  Richard. The resulting battle of wits and witty dialogue pits Bunny's
  fear of losing her job against her dawning attraction to Richard.


The only early computer movie I know that got the idea of 'GIGO' correct, although the portrayed hardware is ludicrous. And Tracy&Hepburn could make reading the dictionary fun.
